# Action mapping triggers wrong method in a controller

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp, portlet

I have following problem. I'm trying to handle two different action mapping in a controller. One is trigger when a button is pressed and second when a link is being clicked.
Unfortunately both action trigger "buttonAction". I don't know how to force link to trigger "linkAction".

Here is my code:

**Jsp:**

```
<portlet:actionURL name="buttonAction" var="buttonActionUrl" ></portlet:actionURL>
<portlet:actionURL name="linkAction" var="linkActionUrl"></portlet:actionURL>

<form:form id="form" modelAttribute="model" method="POST" action="${buttonActionUrl}">
    <a id="link" href="#" onclick="linkClick();"></a>
    <button id="button" onclick="buttonClick();" type="submit"></button>
</form:form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function linkClick() {
    window.location = '${ linkActionUrl }';
} 

function buttonClick() {
    $('#form').submit();
}
```

**Java;**

```
@ActionMapping("buttonAction")
public void buttonAction(@ModelAttribute("model") Model model, BindingResult result, ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response, ModelMap modelMap) {
}

@ActionMapping("linkAction")
public void linkAction(@ModelAttribute("model") Model model, BindingResult result, ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response, ModelMap modelMap) {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onclick handler for the submit button is redundant, since the submit will do this for you.

Also, for your link, maybe just change to something like :

```
    <a id="link" href="${linkActionUrl}">foo</a>
```